# What is the correct way to generate /etc/audit/audit.rules on Centos7?

Tags: configuration, auditd

At the top of `/etc/audit/audit.rules` on Centos7 it tells me:

```
## This file is automatically generated from /etc/audit/rules.d
```

Okay, so I went and looked, and found `/etc/audit/rules.d/audit.rules`. It had the following line

```
# Feel free to add below this line. See auditctl man page
```

Which I did, and found what *looked* like maybe it was the option:

```
 -R file
        Read rules from a file. The rules must be 1 per line and in the order that they are to be executed in. The rule file must  be
        owned  by  root  and not readable by other users or it will be rejected. The rule file may have comments embedded by starting
        the line with a '#' character. Rules that are read from a file are identical to what you would type on a command line  except
        they  are  not preceded by auditctl (since auditctl is the one executing the file) and you would not use shell escaping since
        auditctl is reading the file instead of bash.
```

But I ran `auditctl -R /etc/audit/rules.d/audit.rules` which seemed to work, *however* it didn't do anything to `/etc/audit/audit.rules`.

What's the right way to regenerate that file?

Comment: Looks like you need to restart the auditd service for that to work.  https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/understanding-the-linux-auditing-system-on-centos-7

Comment: @NathanPowell it looks like that was it - the only trick is that you can't use `systemctl restart auditd` you have to do `service auditd restart`...

Comment: [Here](https://github.com/ohdns/centos7_simple_kickstart/blob/master/kickstart/c7_docker.cfg) is an example of how I set up auditd rules in my kickstart files.  Search for zzzAU

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The utility augenrules builds /etc/audit/audit.rules from the *.rules files found in the directory /etc/audit/rules.d.

This utility is called from the auditd service (or you could call it by hand followed by loading the rules files as you discovered - but restarting the service is simpler).

I can't remember the reason why the auditd system cannot use systemd natively. Check the linux-audit@redhat.com mailing list archives.

Answer (score 4):

Regeneration of rules in the file `/etc/audit/audit.rules` uses the rule files contained in `/etc/audit/rules.d/`. That's the case for RHEL7/CentOS7 and, if memory serves, also for RHEL6/CentOS6.

Do the following as root or with sudo: `sudo augenrules --check`

If changes were detected, update with: `sudo augenrules --load`

Any changes made to files in `/etc/audit/rules.d/` should now also show up in `/etc/audit/audit.rules`.

To make sure any change(s) are active, restart auditd: `sudo systemctl restart auditd`

Check if the change is active / in use: `sudo auditctl -l | grep -i [your change value]`

If the change is not found, auditd could be running in 'immutable' mode, meaning that you must reboot for any changes to become active since 'immutable' will not allow auditd changes on a running system, even as root. If running 'immutable', any auditd restart attempts will fail and 'systemctl' should alert you to that fact.